# Bandpass Filter Design 6Mhz/6.5Mhz Center Approx +/- 250khz passband for ATV system

Tags: audio, design, filter, video

I'm looking to build two bandpass filters centered at 6Mhz and 6.5Mhz, with an approximate passband of 250kHz. I want to replace these two filters:
http://www.yoketant.com.tw/yoketant/ceramic-7.htm
LTS6.0MCB
LTS6.5MCB

With a collection of components that I can more easily source from a major distributor like Mouser or Digikey. I'm working on modernizing and shrinking some Analog TV transmitters and receivers in the 23cm band. Here 's a link to the original schematic:
http://tx0rx0.com/?attachment_id=181

The original filters are in the sound transmission system, F1 and F2.
Is this done somewhat easily, or would it be better to try to find those ceramic filters somewhere. I have the book Handbook of Filter Synthesis, by Anatol Zverev, and I can almost piece something together, but I have no way to test it short of building it, and the book isn't terribly clear in some places. Any advice you could give me would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a solution using more "generically available" components such as an LC filter would be larger, more complex and far more troublesome to adjust. Ceramic filters are difficult to compete with, though mainstream suppliers don't pay them much attention. (Looking at Farnell, I see almost nothing below 800MHz nowadays!)

So I see two possible solutions :

Stick with specialist suppliers (Toko and Murata come to mind, possibly Kyocera) and specialist distributors (used to be CirKit in the UK, but I haven't looked for them in years) or:

Transform the problem into one you can solve with available parts : e.g. use an oscillator and mixer as a frequency converter to a band for which you can easily find components; e.g. 10.7MHz. Or something more radical like ADC conversion and digital bandpass filters.

The first is definitely simpler...